# Identifying and disabling all triggers linked to specific table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having the following problem:

I'm inserting data into a table, however, I want to disable future triggers created on this table, that will prohibit my insert from not working.

If you check my code below:

```
create trigger kv_trg_AssetAdjustment_AW on _btblInvoiceLines       --select * from _btblInvoiceLines
with encryption
after insert, update
as

if trigger_nestlevel() > 5
     return

BEGIN

    declare @Asset      varchar(40)
    ,       @Desc       varchar(100)
    ,       @AssetValue float
    ,       @Price      float
    ,       @Qty        float
    ,       @Code       varchar(100)
    ,       @Valid      int
    ,       @Exists     int                                             ------          NEXT STEP IS TO CHECK WHAT TRIGGERS ON ARE ON THIS TABLE TO DISABLE THEM!
    ,       @SL         int
    ,       @NextNum    int
    ,       @Variable   varchar(100)
    ,       @NewCode    varchar(100)
    ,       @Err        nvarchar(500)

    select  @Err    =   '--------------------------';
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   'Please specify a hyphen ("-") between Item Code & Description in the Description!';

    select
        @Asset      =   ulIDPOrdTxGLVAT
    ,   @Code       =   LEFT(cDescription, CHARINDEX('-', cDescription) - 1)
    ,   @Desc       =   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(cDescription, CHARINDEX('-', cDescription), LEN(cDescription)), '-', '')
    ,   @AssetValue =   fQuantityLineTotExcl
    ,   @Qty        =   fQuantity
    from    inserted


    if exists(select Code from StkItem where Code = @Code)
        select  @Exists =   1
    else
        select  @Exists =   0

    if exists(select cDescription from inserted where cDescription  like '%-%')
        select  @Valid  =   1
    else
        begin
            raiserror(@Err, 16, 1)
            return;
        end

    select  @Variable   =   (select substring(@Code,1,len(@Code)-1))
    select  @NextNum    =   (select max(RIGHT(@Code,1))+1 from StkItem where Code like (@Variable + '%'))
    select  @NewCode    =   substring(@Code,1,len(@Code)-1) + cast(@NextNum as varchar)

    begin
        if  (@Asset = 'Asset')
            begin
                if  (@Exists = 0)
                    begin
                        if exists(select @Valid)
                            begin
                                alter table StkItem disable trigger trgStkItemNegStock;
                                    insert into StkItem     (
                                            Code
                                    ,       cSimpleCode
                                    ,       Description_1
                                    ,       Description_2
                                    ,       TTI
                                    ,       TTC
                                    ,       TTG
                                    ,       TTR
                                    ,       WhseItem
                                                            )
                                    select  @Code
                                    ,       @Code
                                    ,       @Desc
                                    ,       @AssetValue
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                alter table StkItem enable trigger trgStkItemNegStock;
                            end
                        print 'The Item Code you specified did not change.'
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        if exists(select @Valid)
                            begin
                                alter table StkItem disable trigger trgStkItemNegStock;
                                    insert into StkItem     (
                                            Code
                                    ,       cSimpleCode
                                    ,       Description_1
                                    ,       Description_2
                                    ,       TTI
                                    ,       TTC
                                    ,       TTG
                                    ,       TTR
                                    ,       WhseItem
                                                            )
                                    select  @NewCode
                                    ,       @NewCode
                                    ,       @Desc
                                    ,       @AssetValue
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                    ,       1
                                alter table StkItem enable trigger trgStkItemNegStock;
                            end
                        print 'The Item Code you specified has changed to : "' + @NewCode + '". Please write this down for record purposes.'
                    end
            end
            begin
                update  _btblInvoiceLines
                    set ufIDPOrdTxGLAssetValue          =   @AssetValue
                from    _btblInvoiceLines   L
                join    inserted on L.idInvoiceLines    =   inserted.idInvoiceLines
            end
            begin
                if (@Exists =   0)
                    begin
                        select @SL  =   (select top 1 StockLink from StkItem where Code =   @Code order by StockLink desc)

                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,1,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,2,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,3,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,4,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,6,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,7,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,8,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,9,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,10,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,11,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,12,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,13,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,14,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,15,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,16,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,17,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,18,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,19,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,20,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,21,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,22,0,0,1
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        select @SL  =   (select top 1 StockLink from StkItem where Code =   @NewCode order by StockLink desc)

                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,1,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,2,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,3,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,4,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,6,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,7,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,8,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,9,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,10,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,11,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,12,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,13,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,14,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,15,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,16,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,17,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,18,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,19,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,20,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,21,0,0,1
                        exec _bspWhUtilLinkStkToWH;1 @SL,22,0,0,1
                    end
            end
    end
END
go
```

If you check where I disable and enable the trigger. My intention is to disable all triggers on this table.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What about `DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON TableName;`?

Comment: I didn't know about that function. Thank you, I will try it quickly.

Comment: Your trigger is fatally flawed. It assumes only value ever in inserted. This is NOT how triggers work. They need to be set based and handle any number of rows. And why bother using "with encryption"? It is trivial to remove but makes things incredibly painful to work with. And trust me, there is nothing in that trigger that is ground breaking. This thing needs a 100% top to bottom rethink and rewrite.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Sean. I will consider your suggestions.

Comment: `exists(select @Valid)` is always `true` regardless of the value of `int` variable `@Valid`. You don't always need to nest `select`s, e.g. `select  @Variable   =   (select substring(@Code,1,len(@Code)-1))` is equivalent to `select @Variable = substring(@Code,1,len(@Code)-1);`. (Or use `set` and `left` rather than `substring` in this instance.)

Comment: "I want to disable **future** triggers created on this table, that will **prohibit** my insert from **not** working." Do you mean triggers created after this one? What does the double negative mean? Does the comma mean that disabling future triggers is both necessary and sufficient to accomplish your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable all triggers on the table:

```
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON TableName;
```

To enable all triggers on the table:

```
ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON TableName;
```

Comment: Thank you Sami! Worked like a charm!